# How do I retrieve a specific value from a table using Azure Database

Tags: javascript, database, azure, azure-sql-database

So this is my code

```
"use strict";
alert("WORKING");
var tableName = "EmployeeCred";


// Add an event listener to call our initialization routine when the host is ready
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("DeviceOnready WORKING");
    $('#add-item').submit(authenticateLogin);
}

function authenticateLogin() {
    alert("AUTENTHICATE WORKING");
    var row, numItemsRead;
    var user = document.getElementById('usernameInput').value
    var pass = document.getElementById('passwordInput').value
    alert("Username submitted "+user);
    alert("Password submitted " + pass);

    alert("creating server database connection");
    var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://strivedatabaseapp.azurewebsites.net'); // define the client
    alert("connection finished");
    var table = client.getTable(tableName);

    alert("reading table soon");
```

My intention is to try to cycle through a database until I find a value that matches both the username/password value taken from the input loginscreen. I understand that I assigned the whole database table into the variable table, but I don't know quite how to cycle through the code. I tried multiple ways but I can't seem to figure it out. I believe I would have to do a table.read().then() but I can't seem to make it work. Any help? Please and thank you!

My end goal is to do something this

```
    if (userInput == userDatabase || passInput == passDatabase) {
        alert("You did it! You logged in!");
        //code which passes user to next page
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to filter data on the server.You could get the answer from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library#table-filter).

You can use a where clause on the table reference:

```
table
    .where({ userId: user.userId, complete: false })
    .read()
    .then(success, failure);
```

You can also use a function that filters the object. In this case, the this variable is assigned to the current object being filtered. The following code is functionally equivalent to the prior example:

```
function filterByUserId(currentUserId) {
    return this.userId === currentUserId && this.complete === false;
}

table
    .where(filterByUserId, user.userId)
    .read()
    .then(success, failure);
```

Comment: Woow thank you! This actually works. I am also wondering if you can help me further with that filter function. Basically, when I find a match for the username/password, I would also retrieve the users ID, which I would use to find further information about the employee. Basically, the employee database would have a one-many relationship, whereby the employee would have many locations/schedule/jobs and each of these has its own database with fruther information on it, which is connected by the ID via foriegn key. How would I go about this? Query?

Comment: @RamonChristianBustamante If it is useful, you could mark it as an answer to close this thread. If you have other questions, I recommand that you could post another SO thread to get help from all of the communites.